# sql search with like or contains

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a table with 2 columns named column_A and column_B .

One row in this table contains in column_A the Value AAA and the column_B the value BBB.

If I search for AAA or BBB with

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_A LIKE '%AAA%' OR column_B LIKE '%AAA%';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_A LIKE '%BBB%' OR column_B LIKE '%BBB%';
```

I get a result.

However if I serach for '%AAA BBB%' or '%AAA xyz%' I get no result.

The value I search for comes from a search form. As long the user types in only BBB or AAA all is fine, the moment he uses a combination of AAA or BBB and something else the search does nor work.

How can i fix that? Do i need to split up the search term like mentioned here: http://www.iamcal.com/publish/articles/php/search/

Comment: You need to split up the search term or use full text search.

Comment: You can refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html link for full text search

Comment: '%AAA xyz% means you are looking for 'AAA xyz' + something not 'AAA' or 'xyz'

Comment: Have you got the search the right way round? If you want to get strings containing column_a, then you need to turn it round, don't you i.e. WHERE 'AAA xyz' like CONCAT('%',column_A,'%')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have tagged php then i can suggest something like this:

```
 <?php 
 $res ="AAA BBB CCC";// your input from use
 $res=explode(' ', $res);
 $sql="SELECT * FROM table where column_A";
 $flag=false;
 for($i =0;$i< sizeof($res);$i++){

    if(!$flag){
        $flag=true;
        $sql .=" like '%".$res[$i]."%'";
    }else{

        $sql .=" or like '%".$res[$i]."%'";
    }


 }
 echo $sql;// resultant sql need not to echo only to show
```

Comment: This is very similar to my solution, so you get my vote. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with regexp like below to search either for AAA or BBB in column_A:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_A REGEXP '.*[A|B]{3}.*$'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all comments, i finally solved like that:

```
$string = $_GET['searchterm'];

$words = EXPLODE(" ",$string);

FOR($i=0;$i<count($words);$i++){$SQLOPTION  .= "AND CONCAT(column_A,column_B) LIKE '%".$words[$i]."%'";}
```

and then added the $SQLOPTION value to my query.